# How to disable build failures with enabled configuration cache in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have:

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.configuration-cache=true
org.gradle.configuration-cache.problems=warn
```

JIB plugin defined:

```kotlin
jib {
    container {
        creationTime.set("USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        mainClass = "com.my.MyApp"
    }
    from {
        image = "eclipse-temurin:17-jre"
    }
}
```

I run:

```bash
./gradlew jibDockerBuild
```

I get:

```
> Task :jibDockerBuild FAILED

10 problems were found storing the configuration cache, 2 of which seem unique.
- Task `:jibDockerBuild` of type `com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.BuildDockerTask`: cannot deserialize object of type 'org.gradle.api.Project' as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types
- Task `:jibDockerBuild` of type `com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.BuildDockerTask`: cannot serialize object of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject', a subtype of 'org.gradle.api.Project', as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types

See the complete report at file:///Users/artemptushkin/gitlab/IptiQ/dx/spring-cloud-config-server/build/reports/configuration-cache/dmnth65ek47ehgnuriyy459yl/ac38wk6b6wvejhas26wg0jngi/configuration-cache-report.html

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jibDockerBuild'.
> Cannot invoke "org.gradle.api.Project.getProjectDir()" because "this.project" is null
```

It passes away when I disable the configuration cache

My expectations are that if I set `org.gradle.configuration-cache.problems=warn` then it **never fails** though it does